# Should this DirSearch Method be public, private or static?

Tags: design-patterns, methods, static, access-modifiers

This method runs fine with just 'void' but is it a good idea to add 'public,' private,' or 'static' to it? If so, what should I add and why? In case you're wondering, this code runs through a directory tree and gets all the file names in that directory tree.

```
void DirSearch(string sourcePath)
{
    try
    {
        foreach (string f in Directory.GetFiles(sourcePath))
        {
            string fileName = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(f);

            if (!listBox1.Items.Contains(fileName))
            {
                listBox1.Items.Add(fileName);
            }
        }                
        foreach (string d in Directory.GetDirectories(sourcePath))
        {                    
            DirSearch(d);
        }        
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        listBox1.Items.Add(ex.Message);
    }
}
```

Comment: Where is the method located? Is it defined inside of a class or a structure? Or is it a free function?

Comment: Add private. If it compiles, great. If not, you should think about why not and if another modifier would be appropriate.

Comment: @CodyGray It's inside the main class. When a button is clicked, the event handler calls this method. Both the event handler and this method are under one class.